# Python3 not found

Tags: python, terminal

When I run python in the command line it's giving me this error

-bash: ‘python3’: command not found

running just 'python3' works fine though, as does specifying the path to python, as in '/usr/bin/python'.

Does anyone have any ideas what could be wrong? I'm on mac OS X

Comment: If you run the python command alone, it should try to use Python2... How did you install python 3?